# Fetch api in react js with whatwg-fetch in IE

Tags: reactjs

I have written application in react js which is fully functional in Chrome browser and willing to adapt the same into IE and other browsers.

I have used whatwg-fetch polyfill for fetch api in IE and below is screenshot it always go to error block of code and says access denied for Anonymous function called.

[image]

Any clues regarding above issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This module support only modern browsers. In case of IE it must be of version 10+. It solely depends on `window.fetch` docs : https://github.com/github/fetch#browser-support

Comment: @Revansiddh i am testing on IE Edge hence it is 10+ version but still it is not working

Comment: Facing Same issue. have you find solution @KOTIOS

Comment: use isomorphic fetch API